# What is that device at an airport which transports packages to the aircraft called?

Tags: luggage, airports, identify-this

I am looking for the name of this:

[image]

It is a vehicle with a long band where you can adjust the angle of the band.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just found it in [Ground support equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_support_equipment#Belt_loaders):

It is called "Belt loader".

Answer (score 19):

This category of equipment is known as "Ground Support Equipment" (see [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_support_equipment)).

This includes a variety of utility vehicles, including refuelers, dollies, chocks, buses and more.

However, the one you're after is the [Belt loader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_support_equipment#Belt_loaders):

> Belt loaders are vehicles with conveyor belts for unloading and
>   loading of baggage and cargo on aircraft. A belt loader is positioned
>   at the door sill of an aircraft hold (baggage compartment) for the
>   operation. Belt loaders are used for narrow body aircraft and bulk
>   hold of wide body aircraft. Baggage stored without containers is known
>   as bulk loading.

Comment: Very useful piece of equipment for getting serious air while riding a motorcycle in Grand Theft Auto.

Comment: @AlanB The More You Know!